# Deploy ASP.NET core web app which used Azure AD authentication on linux server

Tags: asp.net-core, http, azure-active-directory, http-redirect

When I deploy my asp.net core web app which used Azure AD authentication on a Linux server, it runs using an IP address with a particular port number using HTTP protocol. Azure portal does not allow HTTP protocol with IP address. It has to be HTTPS. How can I run my application with HTTP protocol which is using Azure AD authentication?

I tried to add the new IP address on azure ad portal but it does not allow IP addresses with HTTP protocol(only localhost is allowed for HTTP). If I add HTTPS then I am getting error

*The redirect URI 'url' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application ''*

I tried to add full path for "CallbackPath" in the appsettings.json file. When I run the application, I get error of

*ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'. (Parameter 'value')*

I want to run my applciation on a linux using ip address with HTTP protocol. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to deploy .Net Web Application on Linux Server:**

I created a linux virtual machine, like below.

**Azure Portal > Virtual machines > Create >  Create a virtual machine.**

[image]

**Connected to Linux VM Using Putty.**

Install .Net Core on Linux Server by using below commands, See the :[MS document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

**Install required libraries and  .Net SDK using below cmds.**

```
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
sudo apt-get update && \ sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-7.0
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-7.0
```

Transfer the .Net web application to linux server using winSCP, follow the document [here](https://helpdesk.it.helsinki.fi/en/instructions/computer-and-printing/software/transferring-files-between-windows-and-unix-winscp#detailed)

Once copy the files to linux server, navigate to root folder (publish folder) and run run dll.

```
dotnet linuxapp.dll
```

[image]

once ran the .dll files, test the web application using below cmd.

```
curl http://localhost:5000
```

To check the web application on public IP, we need to install **Njnix**, follow the document [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-nginx#2-installing-nginx)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

once install the **nginx**, test the web application using public IP.

[image]

If the nginx application is running, stop the ngnix service using below cmd.

```
Configre nginx -stop the nginx service 
sudo service nginx stop
```

Go to root folder= etc= nginx= sites- available = default (check the permission) by using **WinSCP** and update the location with below values.

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

proxy_http_version 1.1;

proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;

proxy_set_header Host $host;

proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}
```

Once update the files, then start the nginx service using below cmd.

```
sudo service nginx start
```

> Note:  Make sure add HTTP Inbound role on VM, like below

[image]

Run the dotnet linuxapp.dll again

```
dotnet linuxapp.dll
```

Once ran the dll ,test the web application with public IP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When we create the App Services service, it will automatically assign the certificate and then we have to use HTTPS.

**But we can access our Azure app service via http by adding a custom domain name without binding a certificate.**

[image]

And for this error messgae:

```
The redirect URI 'url' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application ''
```

We should check the `App registrations` in azure portal, not `appsettings.json`.